# Postgres not using index when expression in WHERE condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

The table `my_table` has an index on the column `timestamp`.

The following query makes use of this index:

```sql
explain select
  item_id,
  timestamp
  position
from my_table t
where t.timestamp > '2020-05-05'::timestamp

QUERY PLAN
(...)
->  Index Scan using (..) on "my_table" t  (cost=0.57..641762.36 rows=926839 width=52)
```

But this other query doesn't — almost identical but the WHERE condition depends on an expression:

```sql
explain select
  item_id,
  timestamp
  position
from my_table t
where t.timestamp > (select max(timestamp) from other_table)

QUERY PLAN
(...)
->  Seq Scan on "my_table" t  (cost=0.00..33523870.16 rows=343386904 width=52)
```

What  I'm getting trouble understanding is, once the `select max()` subquery has been executed, the `max(timestamp)` value is known and fixed, so how comes Postgres is unable to make an index scan based on this (now known) value? I don't see how it makes sense.

More importantly, how to circumvent this so that Postgres does use the index on `my_table.timestamp`? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Without further schema information, like what the relationship between my_table and other_table is, it's a bit difficult to answer with a query directly, but I've done my best below. As Laurenz Albe mentioned, you could solve this using another query.  That query could take the form of a CTE:

```
WITH max_ts AS (select max(timestamp) from other_table)
SELECT
  item_id,
  timestamp
  position
FROM my_table t
JOIN max_ts
ON t.timestamp > max_ts.timestamp
```

Or a subquery:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  timestamp
  position
FROM my_table t
JOIN (select max(timestamp) from other_table) AS max_ts
ON t.timestamp > max_ts.timestamp
```

Or, if this is called inside a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION 
...
RETURNS TABLE ( ... )
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
    max_ts TIMESTAMP ;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) INTO max_ts FROM other_table ;
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
      item_id,
      timestamp
      position
    FROM my_table t
    WHERE t.timestamp > max_ts ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

I would guess that the optimizer is making a non-SARGable assessment of the predicate and performing the sequential scan because it doesn't know whether or not the index can be used at plan time.  Depending on the specificity of a "cut off" condition, it may still revert to a sequential scan, although I don't know that for certain.  I imagine that would be dependent on your statistics.

Answer (score 1):

The plan is determined before the query is executed, and such a choice cannot be made at execution time in PostgreSQL.

I see two ways:

- execute two queries and use the result of the first in the second
- add a second "cut off" condition like

  ```
  AND t.timestamp > '2020-01-01'
  ```

  that won't change the result, but let the optimizer know that an index scan will be the right choice